# Not getting to boot!

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, macos

Last week I upgraded my MacBook Pro 13" mid 2012 RAM to 8 GB and I had random restarts. So I did a safe boot and everything was fine, two days later the same thing happened again and the  again it was resolved on safe boot.

It happened again today after about 4 or 5 days and I had installed el Capitan beta yesterday on a 30 GB partion.
So today after this random restart problem. I started my Mac and pressed the option key and held it. Then selected my main hard disk to startup and then immediately after selection, I held the shift key so it would safe boot.
It booted just a bit more than half and hung and switched off.
I tried to go into recovery mode, but it booted to el Capitan recovery mode and the disk utility was not working.
If I try boot normally. It restarts 5 minutes after boot.

What should I do?
Is there any way I could change the startup disk without booting so I can  boot into main hard disk recovery mode disk utility and maybe repair the disk or can someone help me troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

You should see if [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) finds anything wrong with your RAM. Turn off your computer, disconnect any external peripherals you have, press the power button to turn your computer on, and immediately hold down D until Apple Diagnostics begins.

Comment: I tried it and it found nothing unusual

Comment: In that case, you could try taking out the RAM and putting it back in. I know from [experience](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179024/85884) that sometimes misbehaving RAM just needs to be moved around.

Comment: OK, will try that

Comment: Is there any other way than that

Comment: Unable to run hardware test also

Comment: It is going to internet recovery when I hold D

Answer (score 0):

I would connect that Mac to another running back and copy any files that are not backed up. Then I would then erase the hard drive/ partition and reinstall whatever operating system I wanted to run on it.