# Will there be issues if I install RAM modules with different sizes in a Mac mini?

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini late 2012 with 4 GB (2 x 2 GB) RAM. I bought another 8 GB RAM module and installed it in the Mac. Should I leave the 8 GB module alone or should I install one of the two 2 GB modules in the vacant RAM slot?

Will there be any issue if there are different RAM modules in the slots (8 GB + 2 GB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro, formerly with 4GB of RAM. A few months ago, I bought an 8GB stick and made the exact setup you're describing. With the exception of [one issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179024/85884) that lasted a few minutes one day (and that I have no proof was even caused by the RAM setup), it's been working perfectly ever since I did the upgrade.

So yeah, you should be fine. Source: My own experience doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

If the two different sized RAM modules have the same specifications (e.g. latency), you shouldn't have any issues.

The advantages - more memory - outweigh the disadvantages of different sized modules - no interleaving memory.

Comment: and it works with my experience a 2012 mini with an 8G and 2G RAM

Comment: This is my answer always since 2013. Add bigger modules to keep a slot free if you don’t know how much RAM is enough or make sure you’re ok selling or throwing away if you insist on installing matching pairs.